# ReadOnly in C# vs in VB.NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, c#-to-vb.net

It seems that VB.NET and C# `readonly` keyword have some differences...

Say, a ReadOnly property in C# can be assigned in some conditions, but in VB.NET - never?

Comment: You don't apply the `readonly` keyword on a C# property - you just don't give the property a setter. It would be *really* useful if you could include some sample code here as to where you believe there are differences.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I Agree, the question tries to compare "frogs" with "honey"

Comment: The question is fundamentally unclear about *what* it's trying to compare. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: Jon, I set a ReadOnly property in VB.NET, and I tried to set its value in the Constructor, this didn't Work, this why this question. Now, wehen I understood I can't delete it )

Comment: If you've asked a question due to code not working as you expect it to, why didn't you *provide that code*? (Did you read the blog post I linked to?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In C#, [readonly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7(v=vs.100).aspx) is a **field** modifier. It specifies that the field can be assigned to only on initialization or in the constructor.

VB.NET is the same, except that [ReadOnly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2b2c2ka.aspx) is also a **property** modifier. It specifies that the property cannot be assigned to - i.e., it is a getter.

Comment: @serhio - oversight on my part - now fixed :)

Comment: "When it is declared", actually ends up as part of the constructor, so the rule is still only in the constructor.

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen♦ for the developer that *WRITES* the code, it is not the same thing, even if for the compiler it could be the same.

Comment: The question has the .net tag as well, for .net, the initialization occurs in the constructor(s).

Answer (score 4):

In VB.NET the read-only property is usually created to be read-only from external class.
If you want to set this property, you can easily do it from inside the class, by changing the realated local variable.

So, e.g. in VB 2010

```
Public ReadOnly Property SomeVariable() As String
```

or in earlier versions,

```
Private _SomeVariable As String
Public ReadOnly Property SomeVariable() As String
    Get
        Return _SomeVariable
    End Get
End Property
```

you can set it from inside your class as:

```
_SomeVariable = somevalue
```

The property value can not be modified from an external class.